# C3js - How to set category label on axis marker

Tags: d3.js, c3.js

I am using c3js to draw a line chart. x-axis displaying labels, which is rendered in between axis marker. 
It is using axis.x.type : 'category'. otherwise the lines are not creating.

But I want to display it on x-axis marker, not in between them.

here is sample code

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
       x:'xaxis',
       columns: [
          ['xaxis','cat1', 'cat2', 'cat3', 'cat4', 'cat5', 'cat6', 'cat7', 'cat8', 'cat9'],
          ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250, 50, 100, 250]
       ]
   },
    axis: {
       x: {
        type: 'category'
      }
  }
});
```

Here is sample code on jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/abhinaw/kyjgzd62.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [axis.x.tick.centered](http://c3js.org/reference.html#axis-x-tick-centered) option:

```
axis: {
  x: {
    tick: {
      centered: true
    }
  }
}
```

See [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Dimmy/kyjgzd62/3/).